# Set of mutex pointers

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, pointers, mutex

I am trying to store several mutex (pointers) into a set.

```
std::set<std::mutex*> mutex_set;    

addLock(const std::mutex* lock)
{
  mutex_set.insert(lock)
}
```

Since that is not working I tried lock guards and unique pointers, but did not have any success. What is the best way to store mutex into a set?

Comment: Please elaborate how it's "not working." Is that perhaps related to the type of `lock` being `const std::mutex*` while the set stores `std::mutex*`?

Comment: I'm still trying to fathom the uselessness of a const mutex pointer in the first place.

Comment: Probably meant to be a const pointer to a non-const mutex.

Comment: is it not possible to have a `std::set<std::mutex>` ? What is not working?

Comment: why do you want to store them in a `set` anyhow? To avoid having the same mutex twice in the container? What would be the use of the set? I can hardly imagine a use case other than locking all the mutexes in the set (otherwise how do you know which one to lock?), which would be kind of equivalent to having only a single mutex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is probably caused by `const`. Code that compiles:

```
std::set<std::mutex*> mutex_set;    

void addLock(std::mutex* lock)
{
  mutex_set.insert(lock);
}
```

You might also consider to avoid using raw pointers - since there is no ownership semantic (ie. who owns and can delete the pointed to object - a mutex in this case).